# Can I create a cookie in a globally available static class?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I want to access some functions from all my controllers. Among the functions is writing and reading cookies.

In previous projects, I have made global functions in a base controller, and made all the controllers inherit from that. But now I would like to do it diffrently.

I have put the class file `AppFunctions.cs` in a root folder called `AppFunctions`:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace Projects.AppFunctions
{
    public static class AppFunctions
    {
        public static void CreateCookie(string name, string value)
        {
            var options = new CookieOptions();
            options.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(120);
            Response.Cookies.Append(name, value, options); // Red squiggly on Response
        }

        // More functions ...
    }
}
```

Now I'm faced with two problems:

1. `Response.Cookies.Append();` is not recognized, and I'm not encouraged to add any usings to make it so.
2. When I try to call `CreateCookie();` from a controller, I can't. The error message is "The name `CreateCookie` does not exist in the current context. And it doesn't help to add `using Projects.AppFunctions` or calling it like this either: `AppFunctions.CreateCookie();`

Comment: 1. The `Response` property is found on the Controller class (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.controller.response?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2). You may use it like that in a class that inherits from Controller. In this case, you should pass it in via the parameters.

2. The function `CreateCookie()` is no longer a function that is inherited from the base class, so the original code has no idea what function this is anymore. Since it now exists in a separate class as a static function you will have to call it like so `AppFunctions.CreateCookie`

Comment: @KingOfArrows Ok, so maybe I'm better off placing it in a base controller after all?

Comment: If the only code that will be calling this method is found in controllers that inherit the base class, then yeah. If you want to make this open for any class to use then leave it in static class, but make it require a response parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Try (response is available in context of controller)

```
    public static void CreateCookie(Response response, string name, string value)
    {
        var options = new CookieOptions();
        options.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(120);
        response.Cookies.Append(name, value, options); // Red squiggly on Response
    }
```

Comment: The type should be `HttpResponse` and not just `Response`